# reorganizing a series of 19 bytes into every single combination of any length

Tags: vb.net, byte, combinations

There are these 19 bytes (I am looking for combinations not the number of combinations)

`17 00 00 00 A4 EA DB 13 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 A3 D3 02 CC`

I need any possible unique combination which matches these "rules":

- at least 4 bytes long
- the order of the bytes can't change(so **17** A3 D3 02 CC is ok but A3 D3 02 CC **17** isn't, because 
  in the original string 17 was at the being but A3 D3 02 CC was at the end)

Let me try giving you examples of possible combinations:

`17 00 00 00 A4 EA DB 13 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 A3 D3 02`

`17 00 00 00 A4 EA DB 13 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 A3 D3`

`17 00 00 00 A4 EA DB 13 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 A3`

all the way to
`17 00 00 00`

`17 A3 D3 02 CC`

`17 00 A3 D3 02 CC`

`00 A3 D3 02 CC`

`17 A4 02 CC`

See the bytes stay in the same order for example the first byte `17` can only in the first byte's place

I don't want combination like

`A4 17 02 CC`

Because now `17` has changed order compared to `A4`

Comment: What do you mean by "combination"? For instance, if you had 3 bytes, would the combinations be '' (empty), '1', '2', '3', '12', '13', '23', '123'? Or do they need to be permuted as well, so that '12' and '21' would be different? (Properly, the term "combination" means that order does not matter.)

Comment: if it was 1 2 3 then the combination would be 1 2 3 | 1 3 2 | 1 2 | 1 3 | etc

Comment: Why do you mention an "answer" if you don't know how to compute it from the byte array?

Comment: I don't understand the provided "answer". Are you looking to compute the number of combinations that satisfy your rules? to enumerate all the combinations that satisfy your rules? or just find any combination which satisfies your rules?

Comment: I personally don't know how it is done, but there is a function I have got that takes a byte array and returns a 4 byte answer. I need to find the combination of bytes (if there is one tbh) that give the answer I mentioned.
As far as I know there should only be one combination that gives that answer

Comment: @Jonathan - I suggest you remove mention of the answer, since we clearly can't help with it without knowing the algorithm behind it. It just muddies up your question.

Comment: What is a "4 byte answer"? How can a single integer result be a 4-byte answer? Or are you saying it's an integer? Is this a homework question? We're all very confused here. Can you please elaborate on what the actual problem is? I have a hard time imagining that the problem is really "rearrange some items in a list".

Comment: Are you trying to recover the input to a CRC function that gives the 4-byte result, "31 85 72 48"?

Comment: Yes it is some form of CRC but apparently it is different in someway. It is not homework either (homework on the 31st of dec??)

It is not going to be a single interger, it will be at least 4 bytes put through some formula/whatever will give an answer of 31 85 72 48.

Comment: Basically I find a combination, it "goes through" a function, I check if it matches the answer, if it does I stop here if it doesn't then I try another combination etc etc

Comment: Downvote because after several clarifications no one seems to understand the problem. It seems crucial that you (Jonathan) first understand the problem yourself, and only then explain it to us, and we can help you find a solution.

Comment: I completely understand my problem, my trouble is typing it out.

Comment: sounds like a brute force password attack to me ...

Comment: No i assure you I am not hacking anything. If I was why would I be asking this question here?

Comment: @Jonathan: "I completely understand my problem, my trouble is typing it out."  Perhaps.  Often, the issue with writing it out is that you *mostly* understand the problem.  It's rare that someone *completely* understands the problem and still can't describe it.  However, keep trying to clarify it.  The more time spent clarifying your answer, the closer you get to completely understanding it.   Don't waste time adding comments -- that's confusing and ineffective.  Instead, spend time fixing the question to get it right.

Comment: I've updated my response to include a C# program that prints out all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim bytes() As Byte = {&H17, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HA4, &HEA, &HDB, &H13, &H2, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &HA3, &HD3, &H2, &HCC}

        Combine(New Byte() {}, bytes)
    End Sub

    Sub Combine(ByVal sequence() As Byte, ByVal pool() As Byte)
        '   test current sequence
        If Test(sequence) Then
            Console.Write("Found sequence: ")
            For Each b As Byte In sequence
                Console.Write("{0:X2} ", b)
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        End If

        '   done if pool is empty
        If pool.Length = 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        '   recurse adding next byte from the pool
        Dim newSequence(sequence.Length) As Byte
        Array.Copy(sequence, newSequence, sequence.Length)
        newSequence(sequence.Length) = pool(0)
        Dim newPool(pool.Length - 2) As Byte
        Array.Copy(pool, 1, newPool, 0, pool.Length - 1)
        Combine(newSequence, newPool)

        '   recurse without adding next byte from the pool
        Combine(sequence, newPool)
    End Sub

    Function Test(ByVal sequence() As Byte) As Boolean
        '   the test function that you haven't provided goes here

        '   this example returns True if the sequence is 4 bytes or more, causing every combination of at least 4 bytes to be printed
        If (sequence.Length >= 4) Then
            Test = True
        Else
            Test = False
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

I leave the implementation of the Test function to you as you didn't provide that in the original question. My implementation basically treats all sequences of 4 bytes or more as passing the test, so it prints all combinations.

I used a recursive algorithm that starts with an empty sequence and all 19 of your bytes in a "pool" of bytes. I then recurse both by moving the first byte of the pool into the sequence I'm building, then by ignoring the first byte of the pool altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea, as others have mentioned, is to use a bit mask of 19 bits and calculate for each number which bytes from the original list should be included.

Here's a C# program that prints all 2^19 possibilities. As before, it does not take into account duplicates:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
    using System;

    class Program {
        private static int[] sourceBytes = { 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA4, 0xEA, 0xDB, 0x13, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA3, 0xD3, 0x02, 0xCC };

        private static bool IsBitSet(int n, int bit) {
            int mask = 1 << bit;
            return ((n & mask) == mask);
        }

        private static int NumberOfBits(int n) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (n > 0) {
                if ((n & 1) == 1) {
                    sum++;
                }
                n >>= 1;
            }
            return sum;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            for (int i = 524288 - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // 524,288 = 2^19
                if (NumberOfBits(i) >= 4) {
                    // Add the bytes from the list that are in the current bit mask
                    for (int bit = 0; bit < sourceBytes.Length; bit++) {
                        if (IsBitSet(i, bit)) {
                            Console.Write(sourceBytes[bit]);
                            Console.Write(' ');
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't really want them. If you really wanted them, you would be devoting your life to nothing else. And you would still never get them all. They're worse than Pokemon.

Comment: you can want, but you can't have. There are too many too compute.

Comment: (23 choose 9) * 14! = about 2**55.  Or is it (24!) / (9!) = abut 2**60. Still too many either way.

Comment: Uhmmm... have any of you **read the code**?  There's only 524,288 combinations here.  It's very feasible...

Comment: @Chip - the question was quite a bit different at the start. My and other people's comments are about the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally understand the question:

You have 19 items, and you want to know how many combinations you can make if you take

- 4 at a time
- 5 at a time
- ...
- 19 at a time.

The number of combinations of *n* items taken *m* at a time is known as "*n* choose *m* " and is calculated as:

*n* !
    ——————
    (*m* ! ) (*n* - *m*) !

So you need to add (19 choose *m*) for all values of *m* from 4 to 19.

You can simplify the calculation by noting that:

*n* choose *m*   =   *n* choose (*n* - *m*)

So you can calculate the combinations from *m* = 4  through *m* = 9, double it to account for *m* = 10 through *m* = 15, and then add the combinations for *m* = 15 through 19.

Here's a bash shell script to do the calculation, which gives an answer of **523128** after about a quarter-second of calculation:

```
# Calculate the factorial of $1.
fact()
{
    local f=1
    local i

    for ((i=1; i<=$1; ++i)); do f=$((f*i)); done
    echo $f
}

# Calculate the combinations of $1 choose $2
comb()
{
    local c;
    local fn=$(fact $1)
    local fm=$(fact $2)
    local fnm=$(fact $(($1-$2)))

    echo $((fn / fm / fnm))
}

# Sum the combinations of 19 choose m, as m = 4 .. 19.
n=19
sum=0
for ((m=4; m<=n; m++)); do
     sum=$((sum + $(comb $n $m)));
done

echo $sum

#EOF
```

Of course, you'll have to remove the duplicates manually.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're asking for a binary number of length (23*8) == 184 bits. I believe there are more such numbers than there are atoms in the universe! The number of combinations is 2 ** (23 * 8).

To think about why this is, simply realize that this is a simple lottery, where numbers are allowed to repeat. You pick one number for the first byte, and that can be between 0 and 255 (256 options). Then you pick a number for the second byte, and that can be between 0 and 255, so you have (256 * 256) options. Then you pick a number for the third byte, and that can be between 0 and 255, so you have (256 * 256 * 256) options (which is 16 million at this point, with 20 bytes to go...)

The fact that you also allow shorter numbers does add a little more to the 2 ** 184 number of possible byte arrangements, but not enough that it substantially changes the tractability of the problem.

Comment: I have changed the question quite a bit which should make the number of possibilities smaller, but is it small enough to be feasible?

Comment: You should explain where you got your numbers 23 and 8.  I don't see where they were in the original problem.  (The problem may have changed.)

Comment: The question did change so please don't vote this answer down

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of the question is that **the order of the bytes cannot change**.

Let's start with a first simplified problem:

1. Assume that each number is distinct.  (Obviously false)
2. Assume that you there is no lower limit to the number of choices (also obviously false)

Then you have a simple choice for each number: Should I include this number or not?  (The order is already given.)  For this simplified problem, you only have 2<sup>19</sup>=524288 possibilities.  That would take a while to print out, but it's small enough to compute.

Removing either simplification leaves you with FEWER possibilities.

So, let's remove the first simplification.  When you are looking at a unique number, you have two choices: either to put that number in your combination, or to leave it out.  When you are looking at a sequence of *n* 00s, you have *n*+1 choices: put no 00s into the combination, put one 00 in the combination, ..., put *n* 00s in the combination.

Therefore, at this point you have 2 * 4 * 2<sup>5</sup> * 7 * 2<sup>4</sup> =  28672 choices.

I leave it to you to figure out how many of these choices have 3 bytes or fewer.